# Unexplained Subversion directory status after checkout

Tags: svn, status, svn-checkout

I am working in an SVN repo with a huge branches area.  As a result, I did a shallow (--depth empty) checkout on my branches folder.

Example: C:\svn\branches

Has no subfolders in my working copy.

Suppose I have a branch called MyBranch that I want to checkout.

I run:

`svn checkout http://svn/ThisProject/branches/MyBranch C:\svn\branches\MyBranch --depth infinity`

Coolio.  I get all the files.  However, `svn status` looks a little strange:

```
C:\svn\branches> svn status
?       MyBranch
```

Let's check info...

```
C:\svn\branches> svn info .
Path: .
URL: http://svn/ThisProject/branches
Repository Root: http://svn
Repository UUID: 3facc57d-2901-0010-8249-59daf7a806c1
Revision: 1733
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Depth: empty
Last Changed Author: e467443
Last Changed Rev: 1733
Last Changed Date: 2010-12-14 21:42:31 +0800 (Tue, 14 Dec 2010)
```

```
C:\svn\branches> svn info MyBranch
Path: ARPE-TEST2
URL: http://svn/ThisProject/branches/MyBranch
Repository Root: http://svn
Repository UUID: 3facc57d-2901-0010-8249-59daf7a806c1
Revision: 1733
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Last Changed Author: v094424
Last Changed Rev: 1624
Last Changed Date: 2010-12-13 22:46:21 +0800 (Mon, 13 Dec 2010)
```

That's weird.  Let's try an add:

```
C:\svn\branches> svn add MyBranch
svn: warning: 'MyBranch' is already under version control
```

My guess is that `branches` has `Depth: empty` so SVN is confused.

Can anyone explain and provide a fix?  Maybe I can ignore.

I am using CollabNet command line tools on Windows.

```
C:\svn\branches> svn --version
svn, version 1.6.12 (r955767)
   compiled Jun 21 2010, 16:00:59
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fetch MyBranch as part of the same working copy use

```
cd \svn\branches
svn update --set-depth infinity MyBranch
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks liked you checked out a branch within an already existing working copy. That's not the correct way, since it created a new (unrelated) working copy withing your working copy.

Answer (score 1):

You are not in the working directory, the Subversion commands only work when your current working directory is inside the project directory:

```
cd MyBranch
svn status
```

You'll find everything starts to work after that.